# "reduce" or "apply" using logical functions in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I cannot use logical functions on a range of booleans in Clojure (1.2). Neither of the following works due to logical functions being macros:

```
(reduce and [... sequence of bools ...])
(apply or [... sequence of bools ...])
```

The error message says that I "can't take value of a macro: `#'clojure.core/and`". How to apply these logical functions (macros) without writing boilerplate code?

Comment: `(every? identity elements)`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Don't -- use [`every?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/every_q) and [`some`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/some) instead.

Comment: Links to docs, [`every?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/every_q) and [`some`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/some).

Comment: `some` does not work very well for `or` as it returns `nil` if the expression should evaluate to `false`. Using `#(some? (some true? %))` or `#(not (every? false? %))` does not add much to readability imo and both do not work too well with thread-macros requiring extra parens around the lambda. Also `some?` only has been available since v1.6.

Comment: @LucasHoepner In Clojure `nil` is equivalent to `false` in Boolean contexts such as `if` tests etc., so most of the time this makes no difference. The only case where `or` returns `false` is when all its arguments are falsey and the final one actually is `false` (after evaluation); the only reason you'd care is if you wanted to distinguish between `false` and `nil` values for the final argument. Accomplishing that with `some` is inconvenient, but it's a rare edge case. `#(some? (some true? %))` doesn't work like `or`, as it returns `false` when applied to `[]`, whereas `(or)` returns `nil`.

Comment: @MichalMarczyk I can also coerce the returned `nil` to `false` by using `(boolean)`. I had the problem that I was trying to use `(some)` in an `(and)` expression and then converted the value to java.lang.Boolean. I did some more testing and agree that you are absolutely spot on for everything else regarding the use of `(some)`. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: every? is going to return a Boolean though, sometimes I use and to return the last element if all elements are true. This doesn't work with every?

Comment: The question specifically asks about `and`-ing sequences of Booleans, and in that context `every? true?` is exactly equivalent (assuming the input sequence is fully lazy – otherwise one wouldn't get the same short-circuiting / non-evaluation (non-realization) semantics). In other contexts, if it is important to know whether `every?`'s `false` comes from a `false` or a `nil` return from the passed-in function, then sure, one would need to use a different approach – perhaps a custom reduction like mikera's. For completeness, `some` does act like `or`, so on that side there's full parity.

Comment: Using some on a sequence of booleans is fine but what if you have a lazy sequence ie. the result of ```(map)```. For example, this returns the correct answer (```true```), but evaluated the functions on all values, rather than stopping at 3. ```(some identity (map #(do (println %) (= % 3)) [1 2 3 4 5 6]))```. What's the simplest way to do this ```lazily```?

Comment: This code works as expected, not printing anything beyond 3 ... ```(some #(do (println %) (= % 3)) [1 2 3 4 5 6])```. However, you may have a function that returns a lazy seq, in which case, you'd want ```(some identity (some-func))``` (ie. ```(defn some-func [...] (map ...))``` to do the same, but its no longer lazy. I don't know if there is a good reason to use a function like (some-func).

Answer (score 15):

Michal's answer is already spot on, but the following alternative approach can be useful in similar situations whenever you want to use a macro as a function:

`(reduce #(and %1 %2) [... sequence of bools ...])`

Basically you just wrap the macro in an anonymous function.

There are a couple of good reasons to consider this approach:

- There are situations where a handy function like `some` or `every?` does not exist
- You may get better performance (reduce is likely to benefit from some very good optimisations in the future, for example applying the function directly to a vector rather than converting the vector into a sequence)

Comment: This may well give *worse* performance. `reduce` *computes* the answer from the whole sequence. `every?` returns `false` as soon as it finds a false element. On my machine, `(reduce #(and %1 %2) (cons nil (range 100000000)))` takes some seconds, whereas `(every? identity (cons nil (range 100000000)))` returns instantly. Formally, `reduce` is linear time, whereas - given any probability of there being a false element, `every?` is constant time *on average*, though linear in the worst case.

Comment: @Thumbnail - very true. Though of course you can get early bailout with `reduce` by using `reduced` if you want. And it doesn't change the fact that raw performance of reduce is faster: for stuff like `(let [v (vec (repeat 1000000 true))] (time (every? identity v)))` the reduce equivalent is about 3x faster at churning through the whole sequence, for example.

Comment: But that only works if you know the number of arguments correct?