# Finding the maximum number of child nodes in a tree

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

First, I should make it clear that this is required for an academic project. I am trying to find the maximum number of child nodes for any node in a tree, using Common Lisp.

My current code is shown below - I'm not 100% on the logic of it, but I feel it should work, however it isn't giving me the required result.

```
(defun breadth (list y)
  (setf l y)
        (mapcar #'(lambda (element) 
              (when (listp element) 
         (when (> (breadth element (length element)) l) 
             (setf l (breadth element (length element)))
           ))) list)

l)

(defun max-breadth(list)
  (breadth list (length list))
  )
```

As an example, running

```
(max-breadth '(a ( (b (c d)) e) (f g (h i) j)))
```

should return 4.

Edit:
Trace results and actual return values, forgot these:

```
CG-USER(13): (max-breadth '(a ( (b (c d)) e) (f g (h i) j)))
 0[6]: (BREADTH (A ((B (C D)) E) (F G (H I) J)) 3)
   1[6]: (BREADTH ((B (C D)) E) 2)
     2[6]: (BREADTH (B (C D)) 2)
       3[6]: (BREADTH (C D) 2)
       3[6]: returned 2
     2[6]: returned 2
   1[6]: returned 2
   1[6]: (BREADTH (F G (H I) J) 4)
     2[6]: (BREADTH (H I) 2)
     2[6]: returned 2
   1[6]: returned 2
 0[6]: returned 2
2
```

Does anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong? I suspect it's related to the second conditional, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If it doesn't return 4, what *does* it return? 6?

Comment: Sorry, missed that out, added a trace result.

Comment: remember that you should not set variables you have not defined anywhere. (SETF l ...) is such a case. l is not introduced in your code. It is not a local variable, no global variable, it is no function parameter, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, standard formatting:

```
(defun breadth (list y)
  (setf l y)
  (mapcar #'(lambda (element) 
              (when (listp element) 
                (when (> (breadth element (length element)) l) 
                  (setf l (breadth element (length element))))))
          list)
  l)

(defun max-breadth (list)
  (breadth list (length list)))
```

Your problem is the `(setf l y)`, which should give you a warning about `l` being undefined.  `Setf` should not be used on unbound variables.  Use `let` to make a lexical scope:

```
(defun breadth (list y)
  (let ((l y))
    (mapcar #'(lambda (element) 
                (when (listp element) 
                  (when (> (breadth element (length element)) l) 
                    (setf l (breadth element (length element))))))
            list)
    l))
```

Then, instead of two nested `when`, use a single one and `and`:

```
              (when (and (listp element)
                         (> (breadth element (length element)) 1))
                (setf l (breadth element (length element))))
```

I find `dolist` more concise here:

```
  (dolist (element list)
    (when (and (listp element)
               (> (breadth element (length element)) l))
      (setf l (breadth element (length element)))))
```

The parameter `y` is always the length of the parameter `list`, so this call can be simplified.  You also do not need to alias `y`:

```
(defun breadth (list &aux (y (length list)))
  (dolist (element list)
    (when (and (listp element)
               (> (breadth element) y))
      (setf y (breadth element))))
  y)
```

You could eliminate the double recursive call through a `let`, but we can use `max` here:

```
(defun breadth (list &aux (y (length list)))
  (dolist (element list)
    (when (listp element)
      (setf y (max y (breadth element)))))
  y)
```

You could also use `reduce` for this:

```
(defun breadth (l)
  (if (listp l)
      (reduce #'max l
              :key #'breadth
              :initial-value (length l))
      0))
```

Comment: @Jiminizer: I just edited to answer the real issue, which I forgot initially ;).

Comment: Why `(reduce ...)` instead of what to me looks simpler `(apply #'max (length L) (mapcar #'breadth L))` ?

Comment: @6502:  see http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_call_a.htm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891707/reduce-or-apply-using-logical-functions-in-clojure.

Answer (score 3):

L is not a local variable, so the function will return the last value assigned to it (ie, the breadth of the last subtree).

Use LET to declare a local variable:

```
(LET ((l y))
    ...
)
```

Comment: Ah right, thanks for that. I find it quite annoying that nothing along those lines has been covered in lectures, and yet we're meant to find a solution without needing additional material.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the correct answer 6? Since e and j in your example are also technically child nodes? If that's how you're defining your problem, the following solution should get you there:

```
(defun max-breadth (lst)
  (cond
    ((atom lst) 0)
    ((every #'atom lst) (length lst))
    (t (+ (max-breadth (car lst)) (max-breadth (cdr lst))))))
```

version 2:

```
(defun max-breadth (lst)
  (cond
    ((atom lst) 0)
    ((every #'atom lst) (length lst))
    (t (+ 
         (max-breadth (car lst))
         (max-breadth (remove-if-not #'consp (cdr lst)))))))
```

Comment: I might not have explained the problem well enough - in the example given, the root node has three nodes beneath it, one of these nodes branches into 4 nodes (F G (H I) J). That's the largest number of child nodes for any parent node in the tree, which is what I'm after. If you look at the trace above, the y argument does represent the correct number of nodes, with 4 being the highest. The problem is, it seems to overwrite that value with 2 when that occurs subsequently.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem better, but is this closer to what you're looking for? (edited original post, version 2)