# In clojure, how to apply 'and' to a list?

Tags: clojure

In closure, how can we apply `and` or any other macro to a list?

This doesn't work:

```
(apply and '(true false))
```

Because `apply` can't take value of a macro.

So, what is the best way to check if all the elements of a list are true?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["reduce" or "apply" using logical functions in Clojure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891707/reduce-or-apply-using-logical-functions-in-clojure)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do this instead:

```
(every? identity '(true false))
```

See [this thread](http://osdir.com/ml/clojure/2010-01/msg01242.html) for more information.

Comment: Anything neater for this use case in recent versions?

Answer (score 7):

In Clojure **macros are not first class things** they don't compose quite like functions, and you cant pass them to other functions, and you can't `apply` them. This is because they are finished and done with before any of the applying would be done.

It is customary to **wrap macros in functions to `apply` or pass them to functions**

```
(defmacro my-macro [x y z] ...)

(apply #(my-macro %1 %2 %3) [1 2 3])

(map #(my-macro) [1 2 3] [:a :b :c] [a b c])
```

the anonymous-function reader macro `#(` makes this so easy that macroes not being first class is really not an inconvenience. Just do try to [remember the first rule of macro club](http://drdobbs.com/blogs/jvm/228700106)

Comment: But this approach will collapse when the macro receives a variable number of arguments.

Comment: you're breaking the first rule of macro club ... yea, even the macro abstraction leaks :(

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this:
    `(apply = true '(true false))`

Answer (score 0):

```
user=> (eval `(and ~@(list true false)))

false

user=> (eval `(and ~@ (list true true 1)))

1
```

I am syntax-quoting and then applying a big sledge hammer to remove the brackets around the collection and since I quoted it, have to use eval. This is useful if you are creating a macro and the function passed in is 'and'.

so `(list 1 2 3)` sledge hammered becomes `1 2 3`.

This is one way, extremely terrible, but it works, so I got that going for me which is nice.
So my clojure isn't great but I hope this macro example clears things up.

```
(defmacro split-my-args-then-apply-fn
  "This is one terrible macro designed to show the use of 'and'."
  [fun coll & args]
  `(~fun ~@((apply juxt args) coll)))
```

**Usage (Never):**

```
(split-my-args-then-apply-fn 
    and 
    {:something :true :something-else false} 
    :something :something-else)
```