# Clojure: Apply or to a list

Tags: clojure

This question similar to say, [In clojure, how to apply 'and' to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218044/in-clojure-how-to-apply-and-to-a-list), but solution doesn't apply to my question. `every?` function returns just a boolean value.

`or` is a macro, so this code is invalid:

```
(apply or [nil 10 20])  ; I want to get 10 here, as if 'or was a function.
```

Using `not-every?` I will get just boolean value, but I want to preserve semantics of `or` - the "true" element should be a value of the expression. What is idiomatic way to do this?

My idea so far:

```
(first (drop-while not [nil 10 20]))  ; = 10
```

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273333/in-clojure-how-to-apply-a-macro-to-a-list) might help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you might be able to use [`some`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/some) for this:

```
(some identity [nil 10 20]) ; = 10
```

Note that this differs from `or` if it fails

```
(some identity [false]) ; = nil
(or false) ; = false
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple macro:

```
(defmacro apply-or
  [coll]
  `(or ~@coll))
```

Or even more abstract

```
(defmacro apply-macro
  [macro coll]
  `(~macro ~@coll))
```

**EDIT:** Since you complained about that not working in runtime here comes a version of apply-macro that works in runtime. Compare it with answers posted here: [In clojure, how to apply a macro to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273333/in-clojure-how-to-apply-a-macro-to-a-list)

```
(defmacro apply-macro-in-runtime
  [m c]
  `(eval (concat '(~m) ~c)))
```

Notice that this version utilizes that parameters are passed unevaluated (m is not evaluated, if this was a function, it would throw because a macro doesn't have a value) it uses `concat` to build a list containing of a list with the *quoted macro-name* and whatever the evaluation of form c (for coll) returns so that c as `(range 5)` would be fully evaluated to the list that `range` returns. Finally it uses `eval` to evaluate the expression.

Clarification: That obviously uses eval which causes overhead. But notice that eval was also used in the answer linked above. 
Also this does not work with large sequences due to the recursive definition of `or`. It is just good to know that it is possible.

Also for runtime sequences it makes obviously more sense to use `some` and `every?`.

Comment: This works only for compile time lists, my lists are runtime lists (though it's not very clear from the question).

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I edited my answer and it now provides a macro for runtime.

Comment: Great, thanks. For me, as Clojure noob, seems `eval` is general solution, but has a big overhead.