# How can I map a macro in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, macros, higher-order-functions

I tried to do the following in Clojure

```
(map future exprs)
```

To get a seq of future tokens. Unfortunately this errs because `future` is itself a macro, not a function.

Is there a way to make this work while still maintaining the `map` syntax? I'd rather not use the `for` macro (just as a matter of personal style).

I suppose I'm looking for a `mmap` or macro map.

Comment: Have you tried using a lambda?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891707/reduce-or-apply-using-logical-functions-in-clojure

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As already stated by Marcin, use a lambda (anonymous function)

```
user=> (map and [true false 0 nil])
java.lang.Exception: Can't take value of a macro: #'clojure.core/and (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
user=> (map #(and %) [true false 0 nil])
(true false 0 nil)
```

*edit*

By the way, if you're using `map` to create a bunch of tasks to be executed in other threads, you might have issues. `map` is lazy, and the futures won't be created until something asks for them. You would need to force it to be evaluated (which is what happens in the repl when the repl prints the result) or find some other way.

Comment: ... so use `mapv` instead of `map`? ... `(defn defer [exprs] (mapv #(future %) exprs))`

Comment: You can force evaluation with into e.g. `(into [] (map #(...) xxx)` I think dorun also exists for this purpose as well. Don't have the time to look it up at the moment though.

Comment: `doall` is what you want. `dorun` forgets the sequence as it realizes it.